# Ionic2 DateTime Timezone Picker

Tags: datetime, ionic2, momentjs

I have a date field where the user is able to pick the date and time:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="DD MMM YYYY" [(ngModel)]="time" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name = "time"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Time</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="HH:mm"  minuteValues="0,15,30,45" [(ngModel)]="time" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" name = "time"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Similar to the above, I would like the user to be able to select the timezone by timezone offset (e.g. UTC+1:00).

How would I include timezone selection in a datetime picker? If this isn't possible, I'm happy to have a separate dropdown which in turn updates the "time" variable in the typescript (potentially using moment?).

The idea would be that this works similarly to Google Calendar, but just with offset as an option:

[image]